# Apache Kudu TServer goes down when I use CTAS (Create Table As) hence my insertion fails

Tags: bigdata, cloudera, impala, apache-kudu

I have a situation where I have a Table in Cloudera Impala (Parquet Format),

The table statistcs are:

**Size**: 23GB
**Rows**: 67M
**RowSize**: Approx 5KB
**Columns**: 308

My Cloudera is
Total 6 Nodes Cloudera Cluster (Disk : 84TB Each, Ram: 251GB Each)

Kudu Master and Tablet Server
2 Master Nodes, 5 Tablet Servers (One Node acts as a Tablet Server as well as Master)

here is my table Schema(Structure)

```
CREATE TABLE SRV_REQ_X
PRIMARY KEY (row_id)
PARTITION BY HASH(row_id) PARTITIONS 5
STORED AS KUDU 
TBLPROPERTIES ('kudu.table_name'='IMPALA_DATABASE.KUDU TABLE NAME','kudu.master_addresses'='host1:7051,host2:7051','kudu.num_tablet_replicas' = '3')
AS 
Select columns* from table*
```

Different Properties tested

```
The properties I have checked and played with are

memory_limit_hard_bytes = Checked with 0 and 1 and 250GB (Same result Tablet 
Server Crashes)

maintenance_manager_num = Checked with 1 as well as 4
```

Records are inserted but at some point this error Comes

**Kudu error(s) reported, first error: Timed out: Failed to write batch of 94 ops to tablet 842e935e768f4a419b193e1fb18e3155 after 329 attempt(s): Failed to write to server: 2d35eb2445e747bea574a5e1af6e0b2a (bda-ptcl1node02.ptcl.net.pk:7050): Write RPC to 192.168.228.2:7050 timed out after 179.996s (SENT)**

I need to insert other tables which are around 102M records and I cannot understand how to tweak Kudu Properties against my Cluster.

P.S The most records went into the Kudu Table were 13M with Following Properties and then the timeout happened.

```
memory_limit_hard_bytes = 250GB
maintenance_manager_num = 4
block_cache_capacity_mb = 130GB    
Partitions: 4
```

Please Help!!

Comment: Which hardware you are using?

Comment: Oracle Big Data Appliance Starter Pack, X-6